# Linux: Attempting to get joystick vendor and product IDs via ioctl, get EINVAL instead

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, ioctl, joystick

I'm attempting to read the name, vendor ID and product ID for a USB joystick on Ubuntu (specifically I'm working with a wired Xbox 360 pad on Ubuntu 13.10 x64). I can read the name but when attempting to read the vendor and product IDs I get an `EINVAL` error. The code is as follows:

```
if (plugged[index])
{
    char name[32];
    std::snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "/dev/input/js%u", index);

    // Open the joystick's file descriptor (read-only and non-blocking)
    m_file = ::open(name, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (m_file >= 0)
    {
        // Retrieve the axes mapping
        ioctl(m_file, JSIOCGAXMAP, m_mapping);

        // Get the name
        char joyname[128];
        if (ioctl(m_file, JSIOCGNAME(128), joyname) < 0) {
            m_name = "Unknown Joystick";
        } else {
            m_name = joyname;
        }

        // Get vendor and product IDs
        input_id inpid;
        if (ioctl(m_file, EVIOCGID, &inpid) < 0) {
            if (errno == EBADF) printf("EBADF\n");
            if (errno == EFAULT) printf("EFAULT\n");
            if (errno == ENOTTY) printf("ENOTTY\n");
            if (errno == EINVAL) printf("EINVAL\n");
            m_manufacturerID = 0;
            m_productID = 0;
        } else {
            m_manufacturerID = inpid.vendor;
            m_productID = inpid.product;
        }

        // Reset the joystick state
        m_state = JoystickState();

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

The snippet that reads vendor and product IDs is:

```
ioctl(m_file, EVIOCGID, &inpid)
```

According the [man page for ioctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html), `EINVAL` the *request* (`EVIOCGID`) or *argp* (`inpid`) is invalid.

How can I determine which is invalid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After doing some more digging I found that the reason `ioctl(m_file, EVIOCGID, &inpid)` fails is that the device I'm opening is a joystick (`/dev/input/js`) and the `EVIOCGID` ioctl is for event devices (`/dev/input/event`) hence the failure. Unfortunately there is not `JSIOCGID` ioctl so I had to change tactics. Instead I'm using [udev](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/libudev/) to access the joystick's vendor and product IDs. Here's the code I'm using:

```
// Use udev to look up the product and manufacturer IDs
struct udev *udev = udev_new();
if (udev)
{
    char sysname[32];
    std::snprintf(sysname, sizeof(sysname), "js%u", index);
    struct udev_device *dev = udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname(udev, "input", sysname);
    dev = udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype(dev, "usb", "usb_device");
    if (!dev)
    {
        err() << "Unable to find parent USB device" << std::endl;
    }

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idVendor");
    ss >> m_manufacturerID;

    ss.clear();
    ss.str("");
    ss << std::hex << udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idProduct");
    ss >> m_productID;

    udev_device_unref(dev);
    udev_unref(udev);
}
else
{
    err() << "Cannot create udev" << std::endl;
}
```

With udev I've been able to consistently retrieve vendor and product IDs for USB joysticks on Ubuntu 13.10 x64.

**UPDATE**

I've tested this further with:

- Linux Mint 16 x64
- Manjaro x64
- Fedora 20 x64

In all instances this code worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit more cleaned up example with minor bug fix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libudev.h>
#include <sstream>

bool getJoystickInfo(int index, std::string& manufacturerID, std::string& productID, std::string& message)
{
    // Use udev to look up the product and manufacturer IDs
    struct udev *udev = udev_new();
    if (udev) {
        char sysname[32];
        std::snprintf(sysname, sizeof(sysname), "js%u", index);
        struct udev_device *dev = udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname(udev, "input", sysname);
        dev = udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype(dev, "usb", "usb_device");
        if (!dev)
        {
            message = "Unable to find parent USB device";
            return false;
        }

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idVendor");
        ss >> manufacturerID;

        ss.clear();
        ss.str("");
        ss << std::hex << udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idProduct");
        ss >> productID;

        udev_device_unref(dev);
    }
    else
    {
        message = "Cannot create udev";
        return false;
    }
    udev_unref(udev);
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::string manufacturerID, productID, message;
    if (getJoystickInfo(1, manufacturerID, productID, message))
        std::cout << manufacturerID << "\t" << productID << std::endl;
    else
        std::cerr << message << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it either pass `-ludev` option to gcc or use following in CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable udev)
```